# Entity Framework Nullable Types not included in the CreateXXX Method

Tags: entity-framework, nullable, field

I'm using Entity Framework 4.0.  I have tables with many nullable types. For a table XYZ the Entity Framework creates an object with an insert method named CreateXYZ, but this method only includes the parameters for non-nullable database fields. 
Nullable fields can therefore not be set on the initial insert.

What is the best way to create an CreateXYZ method that can take the nullable types as well?

Answer (score 0):

The *nullable* values are not included in the CreatedXYZ. You can assign them later.